# MongoDB Atlas connection ip problem with shared host

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

Hey Guys I have a problem connecting with MongoDB atlas it works fine in Heroku and localhost but when I use GoDaddy shared host I got this error and I put IP address 0.0.0/0 but the same problem
error message: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist

Answer (score 0):

go to your mongodb unstallation folder ex : C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin then change the bindIp to your Ip address and save.
After that restart the mongodb server.

Answer (score 0):

Just like your question says you have to check what ip  address GoDaddy is using and add that to the “whitelist”. If I remember correctly there should be a tab for security on Atlas that allows you to add it.

Comment: I did that and also the same problem

Comment: Have you tried a different connection string? EDIT here’s one to try ``` mongodb://<username>:<password>@my-atlas-cluster-shard-00-00-mdyjt.mongodb.net:27017,my-atlas-cluster-shard-00-01-mdyjt.mongodb.net:27017,my-atlas-cluster-shard-00-02-mdyjt.mongodb.net:27017/mydb?ssl=true&replicaSet=my-atlas-cluster-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority ```. You may have to change some parts of it to make it work.

Comment: yes I created a new project and new cluster and same I think the problem with shared host root permission with MongoDB